# how to convert BYTE array to char array for send with socket c++

Tags: c++, byte, winsock

I have some problem.
I write client server app where information send & receive with win socket. On my project need send `BYTE` array to client, and on client this char array convert to `BYTE`, how I can create it, please help me, because `send()` function can send only `char*`. Thank you.

```
WSAAPI
send(
    __in SOCKET s,
    __in_bcount(len) const char FAR * buf,
    __in int len,
    __in int flags
    );
```

Comment: What's the difference between `BYTE` and `char` actually? Do you get any errors when providing a `BYTE array[];` to this function?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ usually it's just that `BYTE` is unsigned. I'd say a simple cast would work perfectly.

Comment: Need correct convert, because I send cryptkey, but I don't know how can convert

Comment: need send BYTE exportRSAKey[140];

Comment: @Vahagn I doubt you really need to ***convert*** something in this case (besides the `unsigned char*` cast maybe). Again did you experience any particular anomalies (compiler-/run-time errors), when calling the `send()` function?

Comment: Error 3 error C2664: 'send' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'BYTE [140]' to 'const char *' 
 14 IntelliSense: argument of type "BYTE *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BYTE b[40];
const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(b);
```