# How do I convert array<unsigned char> to an unsigned char[]?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

In a CLR project I have the output of AesManaged class as a 16 byte array

```
array<unsigned char>^ result = msEncrypt->ToArray();
```

However I need to convert this to an array of type unsigned char defined like this

```
unsigned char buff[16];
```

EDIT:  I did try this but its giving error (no method signature with those parameters, although there is one)

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(result, 0, buff, 16);
```

And this one

```
buff = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>(&result);
```

But the error is *Expression must be a modifiable lvalue*

Comment: please show code for `Byte` and only post compileable (i.e. what's that `^` doing there???) code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert BYTE array to char array for send with socket c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430400/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-char-array-for-send-with-socket-c)

Comment: @EvanCarslake I don't know, I tried both ways but not sure, maybe my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b1fy41s.aspx) I used this and it appears to work

```
pin_ptr<unsigned char>buff = &result[0];
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. Just make sure you don't use the array pointer anymore after `buff` goes out of scope.